# df -P gives me a combination of Mega and Giga byte

Tags: disk-usage

```
$ df -P
Filesystem                                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-rootlv                    20G  613M   19G   4% /
tmpfs                                       7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                                   240M  113M  115M  50% /boot
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-homelv                    20G  2.0G   17G  11% /home
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-instlv                   2.0G  2.9M  1.9G   1% /install
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-optlv                    976M   53M  872M   6% /opt
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-itmlv                    4.8G   10M  4.6G   1% /opt/IBM/ITM
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-tmplv                     20G  2.8M   19G   1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-usrlv                     32G  2.2G   28G   8% /usr
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-varlv                     20G  198M   19G   2% /var
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-loglv                     29G   73M   28G   1% /var/log
/dev/mapper/Rootvg-auditlv                   27G   18M   26G   1% /var/log/audit
/dev/mapper/Appvg-applv                     123G  868M  116G   1% /app
```

I am trying to a add the total Size (add up all shown in 2nd column) 
How do I go by doing that ? as there are a combination of mega and giga

Comment: I am unable to replicate this with `df -P`.  Are you sure you're not using `df -Ph`?

Comment: Check whether `df` is aliased to `df -h`. Use `command df -P` or `\df -P` if it is.

Comment: df -P  or df -Ph  give me the same results

Comment: alias| grep df
alias df='df -h'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-B` option to specify the specific "blocksize" you want all values reported in.  The blocksize is expressed with an integer and units.  From the man page I have:

> The SIZE argument is an integer and optional unit (example: 10K is
>   10*1024).  Units are K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y (powers of 1024) or KB,MB,...
>   (powers of 1000).

For example, `df -BM` will print all the sizes in megabytes.  (It will override a previous `-h` in case that is set in an alias; e.g., `df -h -BM` is that same)

Comment: how would I total that ?

Comment: Use `--total` to ask `df` to add them up.